# UML-XMI to XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi

I am trying to convert .UML (in XMI format) file to XML file by writing xslt code. I am novice at this and would be happy if you can help me understand better. Currently I am only trying to read 1 or 2 elements the input and print an XML output with those elements.

XMI-UML input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<uml:Model xmi:version="20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_OlYJkC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="model">
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="_OlYJkS9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Activity1" node="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw">
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow" source="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow1" source="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Start" outgoing="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<node xmi:type="uml:OpaqueAction" xmi:id="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Load and Enable Timer" visibility="package" outgoing="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
  <inputValue xmi:type="uml:ActionInputPin" xmi:id="_82lIMDRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" name="interrupt">
    <upperBound xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_82lIMTRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" value="1"/>
  </inputValue>
</node>
<node xmi:type="uml:ActivityFinalNode" xmi:id="_F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ActivityFinalNode" incoming="_Hcj3UC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
 </packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

XSLT code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/uml:Model/packagedElement/edge/">
  <xsl:element name="uml:ControlFlow">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output (Only an example.. It can also contain the "node" from input)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sdf3 type='sadf' version='1.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='uri:sadf' xsi:schemaLocation='some_random_location'>
<sadf name='RandomGraphName'>
<structure>
<edge name='ControlFlow1' source='_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw' target='_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw' />
</structure>
</sadf>
</sdf3>
```

Comment: Can you show the output you are actually expecting to get? Thank you!

Comment: @TimC I have added the expected output.

Comment: If the expected output has a `sdf3` root element, why does your code create a root element named `root`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The expected output is only an example. I could change that to root also :) Sorry, thats my mistake but I only gave an example and the intention is to parse an xmi file using xslt to produce xml which I want to later use in sdf3.. using in sdf3 is an option and not a part of this question.

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML and cannot be parsed. Please fix that.

Comment: @michael.hor257k THe input is UML-XMI .. not XML .. and it is just an output of an activity diagram which is not complete but the structure of the XMI is fixed by Papyrus tool...

Comment: The input to XSLT needs to be XML. And XML needs to be well-formed - otherwise it's not XML and cannot be parsed and XSLT cannot process it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can you tell me what tool you used to find that out?? I don't understand what you mean by "well-formed". As per my knowledge XMI is a subset to XML, hence XMI will have XML in it.

Comment: Any XML parser will tell you that - try this one, for example: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you so much. I realised that its a .uml file and not an xml format file. But I will edit the question and update accordingly after seeing other similar questions within stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, an "UML-XMI" is still an XML document, but as mentioned in the comments, it is not well-formed. The issue is with this `node` element

```
<node xmi:type="uml:OpaqueAction" xmi:id="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Load and Enable Timer" visibility="package" outgoing="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
  <inputValue xmi:type="uml:ActionInputPin" xmi:id="_82lIMDRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" name="interrupt">
    <upperBound xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_82lIMTRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" value="1"/>
  </inputValue>
</node>
```

If you scroll to the right, the `node` tag is self-closed (i.e, it ends with `/>`), this means the closing `</node>` tag doesn't actually match anything.

But assuming it was well-formed, the first issue with your XSLT is with namespaces. In your XML the namespace is defined like this:

```
xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML"
```

But in your XSLT you have defined it like this

```
xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML"
```

The prefix don't have to match between XML and XSLT, but the namespace URI does. Additionally, if your XSLT when you use the namespace prefix, you are using it in lower-case

```
<xsl:template match="/uml:Model/packagedElement/edge/">
```

It is case-sensitive though, so `uml` won't correspond to the `UML` which you have defined. The prefix doesn't need to match the XML, but it does need to match the one defined in the XSLT.

Additionally, that template match is also not syntactically correct because it ends with an `/` symbol. That needs to be removed.

Although I am not quite clear what output you actually want, try this XSLT to get you on your way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:UML="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns='uri:sadf' exclude-result-prefixes="UML">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/UML:Model">
    <sdf3 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='some_random_location' type='sadf'>
    <sadf name='RandomGraphName'>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </sadf>
    </sdf3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="packagedElement">
  <structure>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="edge" />
  </structure>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="edge">
  <edge name="{@name}" source="{@source}" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of a default namespace in the XSLT `xmlns='uri:sadf'`. This means all elements, which don't have a namespace, will be output in that namespace.

Also note, you don't necessarily need to code the full path to child elements such as `packagedElement` and `edge`.

But given the following well-formed input:

```
<uml:Model xmi:version="20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_OlYJkC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="model">
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="_OlYJkS9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Activity1" node="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _fE2zwC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw _F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw">
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow" source="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ControlFlow1" source="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" target="_cK4V8C9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Start" outgoing="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
<node xmi:type="uml:OpaqueAction" xmi:id="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="Load and Enable Timer" visibility="package" outgoing="_lieXcC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" incoming="_jzMLIC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw">
  <inputValue xmi:type="uml:ActionInputPin" xmi:id="_82lIMDRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" name="interrupt">
    <upperBound xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_82lIMTRBEeWdiarL2UAMaQ" value="1"/>
  </inputValue>
</node>
<node xmi:type="uml:ActivityFinalNode" xmi:id="_F67sgC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw" name="ActivityFinalNode" incoming="_Hcj3UC9_EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
 </packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

The following is output

```
<sdf3 xmlns="uri:sadf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="some_random_location"
      type="sadf">
   <sadf name="RandomGraphName">
      <structure>
         <edge name="ControlFlow" source="_XjLyEC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
         <edge name="ControlFlow1" source="_ZfIhYC9-EeWyX7UKkcyxiw"/>
      </structure>
   </sadf>
</sdf3>
```

Comment: If we meet I will treat you :)